# Is it possible to retrieve a call without having recorded it?

Tags: call-recording

I made an important call and I want to listen to it again. Unfortunately I didn't install any application to record calls. Is it possible ? Are calls recorded somewhere ?

Comment: Once you make a call, that's it! No further can do. To be able to record calls, is grey-area legally speaking, and also requires kernel capabilities to do so.

Comment: It is Illegal in the US to record a call without the consent of both parties. There is a [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_recording_laws) page dedicated to it. Recording calls is something you should not personally do.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible. At least not on most ROMs. Try the NSA or your country's secret services.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is not possible now. You should have installed some call recording app earlier. 
I see, this call was important to you and you want to hear it at any cost.
Let me be clear if you are thinking about to getting call recording from your service provider then, you can't.
a big No, Service providers don't record any calls and ideally, they should not.
Most of the countries(US/UK/India/Europe and all others) countries have their regulations and Privacy laws to prevent this.

However, in a few cases, your calls might be recorded by the government. most of the countries have provision for call recordings(only with permission of court) and allowed to be recorded by only a few government organizations for an internal security threat.
In this kind of cases, recording of calls can be done by authorized Law Enforcement agencies only with a Legal Warrant.